# How to display data from html form in table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have do that but nothing display. I don't understand what I have done wrong

```html
<div class="">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Clas</td>
        <td>Roll</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>NID</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="displayArea"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="formdata">
  <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="roll"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="class"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="age"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="nid"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
      values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#displayArea').append("<td>" + values.name + "</td><td>" + values.roll + "</td><td>" + values.class + "</td><td>" + values.age + "</td><td>" + values.nid + "</td></tr>");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If that's all of your code you don't appear to have included jQuery.

Comment: open your developer console (f12) and fix the errors you see

Answer (score 1):

First things first. If you forgot to include jQuery, as @Rory McCrossan and @Test Project suggested do that like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The main problem is that first you need to make sure the form doesn't submit itself, but instead let jQuery handle the submit event by adding:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

and before that make sure to give argument to the submit function:

```
 $('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
```

This is the working example.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Clas</td>
        <td>Roll</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>NID</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="displayArea"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="formdata">
  <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="roll"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="class"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="age"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="nid"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
      values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#displayArea').append("<tr><td>" + values.name + "</td><td>" + values.roll + "</td><td>" + values.class + "</td><td>" + values.age + "</td><td>" + values.nid + "</td></tr>");
    $("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
  });
</script>
```

> EDİT: You also forgot to include opening `<tr>` to `append` function. I also corrected that. And it is always good practice to clear form inputs like `$("input[type=text], textarea").val("");`.